# gae cron job for last day of every month

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I want the schedule of a cron job to be the las day of every month. I've used this:

```
<schedule>last day of month 23:59</schedule>
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to launch the job at `first of month 00:00`. You may tweak it to run few hours before setting the `<timezone>` to the timezone with more positive value than the desired one. If desired timezone is GMT than you may set the timezone of the cron job to `Europe/Berlin` and the job will be executed last day of the month at 23:00 GMT.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that I should use a timezone with more POSITIVE value than the one I desire (once it's 0:00 in NY, it's 5:00 GMT, and my job will be late).

Comment: You can always check in your admin interface (`http://localhost:8000/cron`) to verify when exactly (in UTC) will the cron job run in production. [Source](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Python_app_yaml_The_schedule_format)

Comment: It seems that the "schedule" expression should be "first day of month 00:00"   now (2017)

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, the format for the Cron Expression for the kind that you are trying to create is:

("every"|ordinal) (days) ["of" (monthspec)] (time)

Where:

- ordinal specifies a comma separated list of "1st", "first" and so forth (both forms are ok)
- days specifies a comma separated list of days of the week (for example, "mon", "tuesday", with both short and long forms being accepted); "every day" is equivalent to "every mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun"
- monthspec specifies a comma separated list of month names (for example, "jan", "march", "sep"). If omitted, implies every month. You can also say "month" to mean every month, as in "1,8,15,22 of month 09:00".
- time specifies the time of day, as HH:MM in 24 hour time.

I don't think there is a direct expression for what you are trying to do.

You might need to create multiple cron expressions. For e.g. `31 of month 09:00` would address 31st day of all months at 9:00 AM and it should address all months that have 31 days and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid creating multiple cron expressions, since there is a maximun of 20 that I can use.

Comment: dont think this is going to work because you wont be able to effectively deal with leap years for month of feb.